# Rails raises InvalidURIError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I use `redirect_to 'index'` in my controller I get the following error. -on Ruby 1.8.7 and Rails 3.1.1-

```
Started GET "/presentations/1" for 127.0.0.1 at Tue Nov 15 01:48:42 +0200 2011
  Processing by PresentationsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000index
Completed 302 Found in 2ms
[2011-11-15 01:48:42] ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme http does not accept registry part: localhost:3000index (or bad hostname?)
```

And this is how it looks in routes.rb

```
..
get 'about_us' => 'presentations#index', :as => 'about_us'
..
resources :presentations
```

Apparently it's trying to redirect to http://localhost:3000index instead of http://localhost:3000/presentations/index but I couldn't get why. If I use `redirect_to presentations_path` or `redirect_to :controller => 'presentations', :action =>  'index'`, it's all working just fine but why this is happening? I thought I should be able to use `redirect_to` without defining any controller parameter if it's referring the same controller  with the existing setup or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your current routes file, you say

```
/about_us routes to {:controller => :presentations, :action => :index}
```

So, if you were to type

```
redirect_to '/index'
```

It would work just fine. Type, rake:routes in your console to ensure routes are generated as you want them to.

Also, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html might be an excellent resource for you to get started.

Comment: I check the routes, they are okay and I can already make it work like the ways I told. I just wondering what I missing it to work the way it should? I mean obviously there shouldn't be any problem when I use `redirect_to 'index'` but there is. I can't simply ignore a problem like this and use another solution.

Comment: Aha, redirect_to does not take just action name as parameter. Checkout http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html and you can see all the parameters it responds to.